# How to cause switching to another page outside the action?

Tags: reactjs, redux, axios, refresh-token

I use Axios for requests. Created an interceptor for the response from the server. If the server returns a 401 error, I need to take a refresh token and send it to the server to refresh the access token.

Here is the interceptor:

```
Axios.interceptors.response.use (function (response) {
    console.log (response);
    if (isResponseOK (response))
        return response;

    const originalRequest = response.config;

    Axios.post (REFRESH_TOKENS, {
        refreshToken: AppStore.retrieve ("refreshToken")
    })
        .then (function (response) {

        })
        .catch (function (error) {

        });

}, function (error) {
    console.log (error);
    return Promise.reject (error);
});
```

And here is the difficulty. If the refresh token check was not successful, I need to redirect the user to the login page. How to do it? Considering that there is no store, dispatch, etc. In general, those things that are used in action, etc. How to do it?